# Pointers in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, pointers

In one C# maintenance project I came across following variable declaration:

```
Int32* iProgressAddress;
```

Is it pointer declaration in C#?

I thought that there is no pointer concept in C#, what does that statement mean?

Comment: See also these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430112/what-is-the-difference-between-a-c-reference-and-a-pointer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584134/should-you-use-pointers-unsafe-code-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607159/c-benefit-of-explicitly-stating-unsafe-compiler-option

Comment: Here's a nice intro to pointers in C#- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csunsafeintro01.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# does support pointers, but it's limited to pointing to primitive data types that are unmanaged types, such as ints, floats, enums, and other pointer types (plus the rest of the primitives).

**edit**: as well as value types

Comment: Not quite correct. You can have pointers to all *value types*, including structs, not just primitives. But only structs that don't contain  reference type variables.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is.

Notice, that the method is marked `unsafe`. As well as the assembly.

There is a lot of things to know before using pointers from the managed code.
For instance, pointer pinning.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I'm afraid that's a pointer, and you have to get used to it.

REALLY! Pointers aren't that scary. :)