# Working with pointers in C#

Tags: c#, pointers

How can I work with pointers?

Comment: **Don'​​​​​​t**.

Comment: Explain why you want\need to use pointers. That should illicit some better answers and debate. Using pointers in C# can be seen as quite contentious if there is no context to why you want to use them.

Comment: If this topic is not a duplicate and goes somewhere, perhaps a community wiki would be helpful for those who come from languages where pointer usage is common?

Comment: This is somewhat unfocused, is there a specific purpose you have in mind?

Comment: I've heard it said that you start by reading the Unsafe Code chapter of the C# Language Specification *twice* before even considering it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985691/pointers-in-c

Answer (score 2):

Enough has been said about **using** the *pointers in C#*; nevertheless must if you use, here is an [example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rajeshvs/PointersInCSharp11112005051624AM/PointersInCSharp.aspx) of how you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer that already points out that pointers and unsafe code should be avoided if possible.

You want to avoid having `unsafe` code spread out all over your code base so I'd suggest writing a .Net wrapper on top of all your unsafe calls and that way you only need to worry about it in one place. Possibly even create a class library for it, but that depends on what exactly you're doing.

It will obviously be very important that whoever uses the wrapper remembers to call the wrapper's `Dispose` methods and similar to make sure that any pointers or other unmanaged resources are disposed of properly, but that's not different from the rest of your code.

Comment: The wrapper class is a good idea. You really want to keep your unsafe code in one place.

Comment: Implement the Dispose **and** destructor pattern for when dispose is not called.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to avoid [unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8(VS.71).aspx) code. So don't use pointers in C#.

Comment: A better suggestion would be to point out where they might be useful rather than offering up such a blanket statement.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this topic is old but i found myself after swiching from C++ to C# in simulate  behawior of pointer in some case just by using set/get properties. :)